# Preserve the database output sort in dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

I have a requirement where the dataweave output is expected in a particular order.

This is the database output which I have to process

```
[
  {
    "order": "Order 2",
    "inv": 6150579.00000,
    "dio": 31,
    "week": "2020-06-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "order": "Order 2",
    "inv": 6318049.21000,
    "dio": 33,
    "week": "2020-06-08T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "order": "Order 1",
    "inv": 6306077.76000,
    "dio": 45,
    "week": "2020-06-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "order": "Order 1",
    "inv": 6047050.75000,
    "dio": 43,
    "week": "2020-06-08T00:00:00"
  },
]
```

In the DB query I have written conditions so that its sorted with specific order conditions. In this case for example order "12345 - Order 1" must come first in output.

But when I transform the output in dataweave with groupBy condition that sort order is changed

```
payload map {

       "order" : $.order,
       "inv" : $.inv,
       "dio" : $.dio,
       "week" : $.week
} groupBy $.order
```

output:

```
{
  "Order 1": [
    {
      "order": "Order 1",
      "inv": 6306077.76000,
      "dio": 45,
      "week": "2020-06-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "order": "Order 1",
      "inv": 6047050.75000,
      "dio": 43,
      "week": "2020-06-08T00:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "Order 2": [
    {
      "order": "Order 2",
      "inv": 6150579.00000,
      "dio": 31,
      "week": "2020-06-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "order": "Order 2",
      "inv": 6318049.21000,
      "dio": 33,
      "week": "2020-06-08T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

You see the Order 1 value is coming first.

This is an example I had cooked up. In actual I have hundreds of data.
Putting orderBy $$ is also wrong in this case.

Comment: Let me restate your goal: You want to group by `order` and then sort by `inv`, correct?  If so then do the grouping first and iterate over the object to sort the individual arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groupBy() doesn't guarantee any ordering. You should not assume any operation will preserve ordering if not mentioned explicitly. You have to order explicitly the output:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map {

       "order" : $.order,
       "inv" : $.inv,
       "dio" : $.dio,
       "week" : $.week
} groupBy $.order 
mapObject (($$): $ orderBy -$.inv ) // order inside each group by inv descending order
orderBy $$ // order the groups by key
```

UPDATE: based on the comments I have changed the script to order each group by the `inv` attribute in reverse order.

UPDATE 2: I also ordered each group by key, so 'Order 1' is above 'Order 2'.

Output:

```
{
  "Order 1": [
    {
      "order": "Order 1",
      "inv": 6306077.76000,
      "dio": 45,
      "week": "2020-06-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "order": "Order 1",
      "inv": 6047050.75000,
      "dio": 43,
      "week": "2020-06-08T00:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "Order 2": [
    {
      "order": "Order 2",
      "inv": 6318049.21000,
      "dio": 33,
      "week": "2020-06-08T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "order": "Order 2",
      "inv": 6150579.00000,
      "dio": 31,
      "week": "2020-06-01T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I thought someone would say this. I already mentioned orderBy $$ doesn't work. So I modified the question.
I am not sorting based on the value on order. Its done based on the value on "inv" in sql query. So the order values will come based on that condition which I have to group and send to front end.

Comment: What is the order exactly? The order inside each group by inv?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please let me know if I understood it correctly.

Comment: I fixed the order for groups too.